# Invoke format log method of a static logger

Tags: c++, logging

I have some code in my project, but I can't find why I can't got the `format` argument in the log file. When I invoke my logger like this:

```
logger::get_logger().repare().log("log something");
```

But, the log file is still opened and the content "log : " in the `log()` method is shown in log file which indicate a fact that code works. like this :
Expected :

```
======== new log =======
repare.log : Time : 19:05:17. log something
```

But get :

```
======== new log =======
repare.log :
```

I thought the code work around with `vsprintf` is right, which was copied from tutorial.

Here is my code.

```
 class Logger : private noncopyable {
        public :
            Logger();
            ~Logger();
            static Logger& get_logger();
            Logger& repare();
            int log(const char* format, ...);
        private :
            string filename_;
            int fd_;
    };

int my_http::DeployLogFile() {
    char filename[100];
    int fd;
    sprintf(filename, "%s/stuff/log.txt", GET_MY_ROOT_PATH);
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IROTH);
    } else {
        cout << "log exist!!!" << endl;
    }
    exit_if(fd<0, "error in open log file");
    char buff[100];
    sprintf(buff, "======== new log =======\n");
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    return fd;
}

Logger::Logger() {
    fd_ = -1;
}

Logger::~Logger() {
    if (fd_ != -1) {
        close(fd_);
    }
}

Logger& Logger::get_logger() {
    static Logger lg;
    return lg;
}

Logger& Logger::repare() {
    int fd = DeployLogFile();
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("deploy log fail");
    } else {
        fd_ = fd;
    }
    char buff[100];
    sprintf(buff, "repare.");
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    return *this;
}

int Logger::log(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, format);

    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "log : ");
    write(fd_, buf, strlen(buf));

    char buff[500];
    sprintf(buff, "Time : %s. ", __TIME__);
    vsprintf(buff, format, arglist);
    sprintf(buff, "\n");

    write(fd_, buff, strlen(buff));
    va_end(arglist);
    return strlen(buff);
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could state explicitly what you are getting in the log file right now and what you would expect to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's because you overwrote buff with "\n", which of course contains 0 after new line, `strlen` checks for `'0'`, writes only new line `buff` to file. What You probably meant was:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class Logger {
        public :
            Logger();
            ~Logger();
            static Logger& get_logger();
            Logger& repare();
            int log(const char* format, ...);
        private :
            string filename_;
            int fd_;
};

int DeployLogFile() {
    char filename[100];
    int fd;
    sprintf(filename, "%s/log.txt", "/tmp");
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IROTH);
    } else {
        cout << "log exist!!!" << endl;
    }
    if (fd<0) 
    { 
    write(1, "error in open log file", strlen("error in open log file"));
    exit(-1);
    }
    char buff[100];
    sprintf(buff, "======== new log =======\n");
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    return fd;
}

Logger::Logger() {
    fd_ = -1;
}

Logger::~Logger() {
    if (fd_ != -1) {
        close(fd_);
    }
}

Logger& Logger::get_logger() {
    static Logger lg;
    return lg;
}

Logger& Logger::repare() {
    int fd = DeployLogFile();
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("deploy log fail");
    } else {
        fd_ = fd;
    }
    char buff[100];
    sprintf(buff, "repare.");
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    return *this;
}

int Logger::log(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, format);

    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "log : ");
    write(fd_, buf, strlen(buf));

    char buff[500];
    sprintf(buff, "Time : %s. ", __TIME__);
    int offset = strlen(buff) ;
    vsprintf(buff + offset, format, arglist);
    sprintf(buff + strlen(buff), "\n");
    write(fd_, buff, strlen(buff));
    va_end(arglist);
    return strlen(buff);
}

int main(void){

    Logger::get_logger().repare().log("%s", "log something");
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
======== new log =======
repare.log : Time : 19:05:17. log something
```

But then - probably it's NOT something you really wanted - since trying to write:

```
Logger::get_logger().repare().log("%s", "log something");
Logger::get_logger().repare().log("%s %d %s", "crazy whatamai", 42, "log even more");
```

would leave you with

```
log exist!!!
======== new log =======
repare.log : Time : 19:06:17. crazy whatamai 42 log even more
```